# Добавить класс по клику на select, удалить этот класс по клику на option

Tags: jquery, select

Добавить класс по клику проблем нет, но вот убрать по клику на `option` этого же `select` не выходит. Ведь получается, что и по `select` я кликаю тоже.

```
$('.select option').click(function(){
            $(this).parents('.select_box').removeClass('open_select');
        });

        $('.select').click(function(){
            $(this).parents('.select_box').addClass('open_select');
        });
```

Есть какие-то хитрости?

Comment: А зачем это надо?

Comment: @Qwertiy, тобы при раскрытии списка стрелка сиотрела вверх, а при закрытии - вниз  сам список полностью прозрачный, содержииое выбранного пункта перекидывается в span с классом select_box, у него в бэкграунде стрелка

Comment: Т. е. select уже кастомный, и он не умеет менять стрелку? А можно код на jsfiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cgc9m55z/ я уже и с bind/unbind пробую - всё не то

Comment: @Qwertiy, селект не кастомный, на его месте span, в который перекидывается текст из селекта